# 360-Panoramic Video using Google-VR-SDK on Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, google-vr, 360-panorama

I modified the gvr-android-sdk "sdk-simplevideowidget" (just removed some text and changed the video to a custom one) and compiled it for API 23, supporting API 19 minimum (using the latest android-studio):

- It works on a Tablet running API 19
- It works on a Phone running API 22 (gyro & cardboard working like a charm!)
- It **doesn't** work on a tablet running API 23

Now for the strange thing: Instead of *just not working*, the video is just flickering purple with all the elements contained in the app (text and even the icon) in negative arranged in panoramic (like in a "swirl")... see this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX5ao.png).

Unfortunately, I am currently not able to debug on the tablet, as I have no direct access to it.

Does anyone have any idea on this "bug's" origin? Do I have to alter the build-settings in order for it to work on API 23?

Answer (score 0):

Well... I just took a look at the open issues over at [gvr-android-sdk's GitHub](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/issues) and found [this](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/issues/75).

Apparently, this is some sort of driver-related bug occurring on many Samsung-Devices (in my case the Galaxy 2). They announced a fix for this in their next release (early july).